# Transform an MSI by adding a Powershell script with Orca

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, orca

I have to deploy a virtual printer software with a GPO. The MSI installer given by the publisher works fine but there is no option for setting the virtual printer as default in the installation process.

So I created this "simple" powershell script to change the default printer.

```
## Get the Printer with WMI
$printer = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_Printer Where Name = 'GreenPrint'"

## Set printer as default printer
$printer.SetDefaultPrinter()
```

Executing this script manualy after the installation is working fine but
is there a way to include this script in the installation process of the MSI by using a transform file (.mst).

Thanks for your answers

**Full installation with Powershell**

Based on the proposition of Niklas Sjögren, I have created a Powershell script which install the MSI package then set the printer as default. As GPO doesn't give an option for running only once a script on login, I use a registery key to check if we need to process.

I think you better have to use this kind of script on the initial configuration of your Workstation instead of using a logonscript !

```
## Custom variables

$CompanyName = ‘YourCompany’
$InstallDir = "Path\Installer.msi"

## Set registry information for the local machine

$CompanyRegPath = "HKLM:\Software\"+$CompanyName

if (Test-Path $CompanyRegPath)
  {}
else
  {New-Item -path "HKLM:\Software\" -name $CompanyName}

if (Test-Path $CompanyRegPath'\Green Print')
  {}
else
  {New-Item -path $CompanyRegPath -name "Green Print"}

if ((Get-ItemProperty $CompanyRegPath'\Green Print').IsDeployed -eq $null)
  {Set-ItemProperty $CompanyRegPath'\Green Print' -name IsDeployed -Value 0}

#Retrieve registry information   
$IsDeployed = (Get-ItemProperty $CompanyRegPath'\Green Print').IsDeployed

if ($IsDeployed -ne 0)
  {}  
else
  {  
  ## Install the virtual printer software
  Start-Process $InstallDir /qn -Wait

  ## Get the Printer object with WMI
  $printer = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_Printer Where Name = 'GreenPrint'"

  ## Set the Printer object as default printer
  $printer.SetDefaultPrinter()

  #Update the IsDeployed in registry
  Set-ItemProperty $CompanyRegPath’\Green Print’ -name IsDeployed -Value -1
  }
```

Comment: how do you add the msi? an idea can be to simply run the msi via a cmd-file instead and add the powershell.exe -file \\*path* to a new line

Comment: I deploy the .msi with a Group Policy Object (Assign a MSI Package). Using a GPO with a "run once script" could be a work around as I don't think I really need to update/uninstall this package with the original Policy.

Comment: is this a printer supposed to be standard for everyone? or more than at least a few users? in that case i would suggest a logon script with the included code. We use the same at our company and it works great. (if you use 2012 or above functional level, be aware of the built in 5min delay on logon scripts)

Comment: Yes the printer is supposed to be standard (Look at https://www.printgreener.com/ to have an idea of the purporse of this virtual printer). But I don't want to force it "as default" on every logon as I'm sure someone could found a good reason of not using it. That why the script should be "run once/part of" the installation process. I Will test the script install instead of msi assignement tomorrow.